# How to structure ansible script to create instances or not to create instances

Tags: ansible

I have ansible scripts to build out infrastructure on existing server instances. My inventory files specifies all the hosts and the playbooks operates on instances in my inventory file.

My question is: what is the best practice for building out new instances? should it be includes in the scripts that setup the environment or separated? I'm a bit confused how the script could create instances (say EC2 instances) and accept inventory files.

Comment: Have you read http://docs.ansible.com/guide_aws.html and http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html? If so, please explain why these articles don't address your question.

Comment: @Mxx i have not seen that article and it's interesting. what I'm actually trying to figure out is when i setup my infrastructure with playbooks, is it best practice to only configure servers and have another playbook for building out new server instances. I am unsure of the best practice and that's what I'm really hoping someone shed some light on.

Comment: It all depends on your specific use-case, needs, skill set. It's very much personal preference. One could say a perfect vision to be a single collection of playbooks that does absolutely everything from bringing up servers to deploying code. Another might be perfectly fine to have separate playbooks for provisioning, configuration and deployments. But there's also http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html

Answer (score 1):

May be that example playbook will help you, it will create the instance(s) for you and then run the tasks/roles on these created instances all in one, it will also add the ip of the newly created instances into the host file(suppose it's in the same directory,from where you are running this playbook):

```
---
  - name: Provision an EC2 Instance
    hosts: local
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tags: provisioning
    # Necessary Variables for creating/provisioning the EC2 Instance
    vars:
      instance_type: t1.micro
      security_group: test-sg
      image: ami-98aa1cf0
      region: us-east-1
      keypair: ansible
      count: 1

    # Task that will be used to Launch/Create an EC2 Instance
    tasks:

      - name: Create a security group
        local_action: 
          module: ec2_group
          name: "{{ security_group }}"
          description: Security Group for Servers
          region: "{{ region }}"
          rules:
            - proto: tcp
              type: ssh
              from_port: 22
              to_port: 22
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
            - proto: tcp
              from_port: 6800
              to_port: 6800
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0
          rules_egress:
            - proto: all
              type: all
              cidr_ip: 0.0.0.0/0


      - name: Launch the new EC2 Instance
        local_action: ec2 
                      group={{ security_group }} 
                      instance_type={{ instance_type}} 
                      image={{ image }} 
                      wait=true 
                      region={{ region }} 
                      keypair={{ keypair }}
                      count={{count}}
        register: ec2

      - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group 
        local_action: lineinfile 
                      dest="./hosts" 
                      regexp={{ item.public_ip }} 
                      insertafter="[ec2server]" line={{ item.public_ip }}
        with_items: ec2.instances


      - name: Wait for SSH to come up
        local_action: wait_for 
                      host={{ item.public_ip }} 
                      port=22 
                      state=started
        with_items: ec2.instances

      - name: Add tag to Instance(s)
        local_action: ec2_tag resource={{ item.id }} region={{ region }} state=present
        with_items: ec2.instances
        args:
          tags:
            Name: test

      - name: SSH to the EC2 Instance(s)
        add_host: hostname={{ item.public_ip }} groupname=ec2server
        with_items: ec2.instances

  - name: Install these things on Newly created EC2 Instance(s)
    hosts: ec2server
    sudo: True 
    remote_user: ubuntu
    gather_facts: True
    # Run these tasks  
    tasks:
      - include: tasks/upgrade.yml
```

And your hosts file will be look like this:

```
[local]
localhost

[ec2server]
```

Hope, this will help you. Thanks